# SQL Update using subquery in where statement error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update the emails of all customers who are located in the 'United States' by referencing the Country table however I keep getting returned an error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'country' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

```
Update Customer
Set email = concat(substr(first_name,1,1), last_name,'@sakilacustomer.com.us')
where country in(Select country From customer
join address using(address_id)
join city using(city_id)
join country using(country_id)
Group by country
Having country = 'United States');
```

Also tried...

```
Update Customer
Set email = concat(substr(first_name,1,1), last_name, '@sakilacustomer.com.us')
where country in(Select country From country where country = 'United States');
```

I am providing an image of the EER Diagram that can be used as a reference

[image: EER Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

This seems so complicated.  How about this?

```
Update Customer c join
       address a
       using (address_id) join
       city ci
       using (city_id) join
       country co
       using (country_id)
    set c.email = concat(left(c.first_name, 1), clast_name, '@sakilacustomer.com.us')
where co.country = 'United States';
```

Somehow, I think the issue with your query is that `customer` doesn't have `country`, so the error is the `country in` rather than inside the subquery.  The error message itself is rather confusing, though.

Comment: Yeah thank you that is also where I was confused... Thank you for the reply it did work when I used a join after the update with alias

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 Update a
 set a.email = concat(substr(first_name,1,1), last_name,'@sakilacustomer.com.us')
 from customer a join 
(select * from  customer a
join address b on a.address_id=b.address_id
join city c on a.city_id=c.city_id
join country d on a.country_id=d.country_id 
where country='united states'
 ) b 
 on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
```

Comment: Can't have a 'From' statement after 'Set'

Comment: Should be able to if you are updating on a join - are you working in sql server?

Comment: @DanielMarcus The syntax is `UPDATE <tablename> <alias> JOIN (<subquery>) <alias> SET ... WHERE ...`. You can't rearrange the order of clauses in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
update Customer
set email = concat(substr(first_name,1,1), last_name, '@sakilacustomer.com.us')
where customer_id in (
    select customer_id
    from customer join address using(address_id)
         join city using(city_id)
         join country using(country_id)
    where country = 'United States'
);
```